# how to access mongodb deployed insde lxc container

Tags: lxc, ubuntu-15.04, lxd

I have been playing with lxc-lxd. I was able to install mongodb within an lxc container (ubuntu 15.04). I was able to access everything from within the container but not the otherway around. The container & lxc-bridge were being given 10.x.x.x ip address where as my network router IP address starts with 192.x.x.x. How do I access mongodb from outside the container (out side the host as well). I am planing to create a couple of more containers for nginx & node.js, so host pass through may not be an option.

My Ubuntu host is running within a virtualbox VM, hope this is not causing the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create a bridge as per instructions here https://wiki.debian.org/LXC/SimpleBridge

My interface was showing em1 instead of eth0 so be sure to replace eth0 with whatever you got.

```
# Comment out the following:
# The primary network interface
#allow-hotplug eth0
#iface eth0 inet dhcp

auto br0
iface br0 inet dhcp
        bridge_ports eth0
        bridge_fd 0
        bridge_maxwait 0
```

Then create your container with a profile:

```
lxc profile create bridged
lxc profile device add bridged eth0 nic nictype=bridged parent=br0
lxc launch ubuntu/vivid test --profile=bridged
```

again replace eth0 with whatever you got, I think this is redundant given we already has a bridge called br0, in fact I did this in reverse order. Created the profile and the container but I got the following error:

```
Error calling 'lxd forkstart db01 /var/lib/lxd/containers /var/log/lxd/db01/lxc.conf': err='exit status 1'
```

Fixed this by creating the bridge as described above.

Comment: Note that you can also just changed the default profile with:

    lxc profile edit default